# Why can't I place a banner on a shield in Minecraft Bedrock Edition?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I want to make a cool shield, and it will not work on a crafting table. I designed the banner, yet it won't work.[image: Crafting recipe]

Answer (score 2):

Actually, not to burst anyone's bubble, but this is real and you can customize your shields but only in Java. So alternatively, only for PC. And if you're playing Java the banner should be in the first square of the middle row and the shield should be in the second square of the middle row.

Answer (score 0):

Shield designs cannot be done in Bedrock edition, unfortunately.  Perhaps a behavior pack could be made to enable it, but it is not vanilla.